# Can I Use Joomla Plugins in my component

Tags: php, plugins, joomla, components

Can i use any joomla plugin like "visg" in my component ?
if yes what the code ?

Comment: Please state where do you want to use and how do you want to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes but it will depend on what events a plugin responds.
2. Joomla! plugins responds to a [series of trigger events depending on their type](http://docs.joomla.org/Plugin)
3. You have have add [support for the event in your component](http://docs.joomla.org/Supporting_plugins_in_your_component)

Most of the documents linked to talk about 1.5 but it's not that different - mostly just a [few renamed events](http://docs.joomla.org/Adapting_a_Joomla_1.5_extension_to_Joomla_1.6#Renamed_Events).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at these links:

http://docs.joomla.org/Supporting_plugins_in_your_component

http://docs.joomla.org/Using_plugins_in_your_own_extension

Answer (score 0):

Give a look on following refrences,this will solve ur problem:-
http://docs.joomla.org/Using_plugins_in_your_own_extension
http://docs.joomla.org/Supporting_plugins_in_your_component
http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=340926
http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=304&t=341016